# Question regarding FILTER function and dependent dropdown lists

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, dropdown

I'm learning excel and I've been toying around with the idea of having multiple dependent dropdown lists, where all of them depend on the same cell, which also happens to be a dropdown list.

For example, in this scenario:

[image]

By selecting T-Shirt under Piece, the only options you would get in a dropwdown under Size and Color would be S, M, L and Black, Red and Yellow respectively. Both Size and Color would be dependent on the same cell, under Piece.

If it was just one dependent dropdown list it would be easy using `INDIRECT` and chaning the name of ranges. From my understanding, it would also be possible with many helper columns using `FILTER` and then redirecting the cells to those columns, but that also doesn't feel like the most optimal solution.

Is what I'm proposing possible at all? Thank you for any help you can give me. English isn't my first language so I apologize if anything looks confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Filter directly in a validation list (you need to created a named range to do that), but you can use XLOOKUP, which can return an array. So a simple example like the following works, nothing special involved

[image]

DV List formulas:

Piece `=$A$3:$A:$5`
Size `=XLOOKUP(A9,$C$2:$E$2,$C$3:$E$5)`
Color`=XLOOKUP(A9,$G$2:$I$2,$G$3:$I$5)`

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

**METHOD 1:**

One option would be to stick with the INDIRECT method by appending "Size" and "Color" to your Named Ranges. So, in this case, you would have a named range for ***TShirtSize, TShirtColor, ShirtSize, ShirtColor, HoodieSize, and HoodieColor***. Then, an example of the INDIRECT formula used in Data Validation would be...

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($A8,"-","")&B$7)
```

...where `A8:A10` contains the clothing pieces and `B7:C7` contains the column headers "Size" and "Color". The SUBSTITUTE function is also needed to remove the invalid character "-" from "T-Shirt".

[image: indirect_validation.png]
**Figure 1:** Data Validation with INDIRECT and Concatenation

**METHOD 2:**

With Office 365, another option would be to use an XLOOKUP based LAMBDA function to simulate the FILTER function. To create a custom LAMBDA function, open **Name Manager** and create a **New Name**. Name it "**ListFilter**" and paste the following formula into the "*Refers to:*" field:

```
=LAMBDA(piece,type,table_range,
LET(
   _col1, INDEX(table_range,,1),
   _col2, INDEX(table_range,,2),
   _col3, INDEX(table_range,,3),
XLOOKUP(1, (_col1=piece)*(_col2=type), _col3):
   XLOOKUP(1, (_col1=piece)*(_col2=type), _col3,,,-1)))
```

This method requires a slightly different setup of your lookup values. They should be organized in a table-like structure as follows:

| Piece | Type | Options |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T-Shirt | Size | S |
| T-Shirt | Size | M |
| T-Shirt | Size | L |
| T-Shirt | Color | Black |
| T-Shirt | Color | Red |
| T-Shirt | Color | Yellow |
| Shirt | Size | S |
| Shirt | Size | M |
| Shirt | Color | White |
| Shirt | Color | Black |
| Shirt | Color | Gray |
| Shirt | Color | Blue |
| Hoodie | Size | M |
| Hoodie | Size | L |
| Hoodie | Size | XL |
| Hoodie | Color | Blue |
| Hoodie | Color | Black |
| Hoodie | Color | Green |

Note how each "Piece" and "Type" are grouped together in the list. This is essential for returning the applicable options only. Then, an example of the custom **ListFilter** function used in Data Validation would be...

```
=ListFilter($E2,F$1,$A$2:$C$19)
```

...where column E contains the clothing pieces and `F1:G1` contains the column headers "Size" and "Color".

[image: lambda_validation.png]
**Figure 2:** Data Validation with custom LAMBDA function

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

The reason the FILTER function cannot be used directly within Data Validation, but XLOOKUP can, is because FILTER returns an array object, whereas XLOOKUP returns a range object.

The custom **ListFilter** function mimics the FILTER function by joining two XLOOKUP functions with the range operator (colon). The first XLOOKUP is searching from “first-to-last” by default, whereas the second XLOOKUP has the optional *[search_mode]* parameter set to -1, so it’s searching from “last-to-first”. The result is a range from the first item found to the last item found. For example, where *piece*=“Shirt” and *type*=“Color” it will return range `C10:C13`.

[image: data_validation.png]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the drop-down list function does not support the FILTER function. Having that said, there are already other ways being suggested to meet the desired outcome, and I am just adding one more to the solution list :)

Firstly, need to restructure your data in the following way:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rngSupport1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| rngSupport2 | S | S | S | C | C | C |
| rngData | S | S | M | B | W | R |
|  | M | M | L | R | B | B |
|  | L |  | XL | Y | G |  |

Assuming range B1:G1 is named as 'rngSupport1', being the different cloth types in your case;

Assuming range B2:G2 is named as 'rngSupport2', being either size or color in your case

Assuming range B3:G5 is named as 'rngData', being the various options in your case

Highlight range B8:C10 as shown in the following screenshot, go to data validation, select List as the validation type, enter the following formula in the source field, then hit OK. There you go :)

```
=INDEX(rngData,,MATCH($A8&B$7,rngSupport1&rngSupport2,0))
```

[image]